# Run Coroutine with delay in doze mode

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, delay, doze

I am trying to implement an idle time lock feature. Has coroutine had some restrictions in doze mode? As delay doesn't seem to work once the device is in doze mode

```
var scope: CoroutineScope = MainScope()

fun scheduleIdleTimer(time: Long) {
    scope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    scope.launch {
        delay(time)
        if (isActive) {
            initiateIdleLock()
        }
    }
}
```